# AppleScript, why does first "display alert" work but then cause AppleScript icon to bounce, waiting for me to click it until I get another dialog?

Tags: macos, applescript

NOTE: I do not have Admin privileges, and cannot use things that require assistance or accessibility or whatever it is!

I'm basically trying to write an execution of a script that sets up my macOS Desktop by opening apps, positioning them etc
Part of that is allowing me to click continue on a dialogue after doing certain things I have to do manually as a result of the limitation (positioning a few apps for example).

I can successfully have the first alert pop up, and when I press OK, it executes the task, but then the 2nd alert is hidden behind AppleScript and will not pop up until I click AppleScript. Anyone know why?

Heres what I have, and please keep in mind I do not have Admin privileges, which means I can't use System Events:

```
tell application "Script Editor"
    set miniaturized of window 1 to true
end tell

display alert "App is opening. Make sure you log-out of Apple Connect!"
delay 3
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document
    set the bounds of the front window to {1077, 23, 1581, 464}
    tell window 1
        set URL of tab 1 to "http://appwebsite.com"
    end tell
end tell

display alert "Set up App, sign into Apple then click OK to open all other Safari windows"
delay 1

tell application "Test Task App" to activate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place an `activate` *command* before the `display alert` *command* so **Script Editor** has focus and the `display alert` *command* will not be hidden.

Example:

```
activate
display alert "Set up App, sign into Apple then click OK to open all other Safari windows"
```

You do not need it before the first one as **Script Editor** has focus with it runs the first `display alert` *command*, but once you `activate` **Safari**, the `display alert` *command* is behind **Safari**. So if you use an `activate` *command* before the `display alert` *command*, it brings it forward in front of, in this case, **Safari**.